# How to translate the following rally lookback api request to the Ext request equivalent?

Tags: rally

So I have this lookback API request:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/xxxxxxx/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"ObjectID":92444754348,"__At":"2017-02-23T00:00:00Z"}&fields=true&start=0&pagesize=10&removeUnauthorizedSnapshots=true
```

How can I make that request using the Ext equivalent. I have tried many ways, including this one:

```
let snapshot = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
            find: {
                ObjectID: 92444754348,
                __At: "2017-02-23T00:00:00Z"
            }
        });

        return snapshot.load();
```

This example returns an object that has the field "raw", which to my understanding is supposed to have all the artifact's fields along with the values they had at the specified time. But, "raw" only has ObjectID, Project, _ValidFrom, and _ValidTo.

Right now I'm able to solve my issue by using an ajax GET request and parsing the JSON; but I would like to use the Ext solution instead (which seems to be the recommended one).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include a fetch in your config when you're creating the store it will autocreate the correct model for you.

```
let snapshot = Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
        find: {
            ObjectID: 92444754348,
            __At: "2017-02-23T00:00:00Z"
        },
        fetch: ['ObjectID'] //add all the fields you want here
    });
```

`fields=true` is a nice shorthand to get all the data back, but the store/model have no idea how to interpret that...

The store also has config properties for compress, removeUnauthorizedSnapshots and most of the other parameters Lookback Api supports.